# What does this GNOME button do?

Tags: gnome

I am running GNOME 3.14.4 and I can't find what is the purpose of one of the bottom buttons in the GNOME system menu.

[image]

The four bottom buttons can be used to, in order:

1. Access system settings
2. ?
3. Lock the screen
4. Restart or power off the machine

What does the second button do? It is a toggle control -- when clicked, its icon changes from a circled arrow to a circled arrow with padlock.  The first thing that came to my mind is screen rotation, but it's just a wild guess.